# Request a Specific OpenGL Context Version in GLFW3

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, glfw

How would I detect what OpenGL versions are supported on the current system, and how to 'choose' one of them to use? On context creation I know it automatically picks one for you which is backwards-compatible, but I want to select one my own.

I'm not using GLEW or any other library like that, just plain OpenGL and GLFW3.

Comment: You cannot create an OpenGL context using "plain OpenGL." You have to use a window system API such as WGL, GLX, CGL, EGL, etc. These APIs were all extended around the time GL 3.0 was released to introduce this functionality. If you don't want to be bothered writing platform-specific code, you should consider a framework like GLFW3. But know that for implementations older than 3.x, there is no way to request a specific version.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I actually am using GLFW3, but I'm not sure if I'll keep using it. Is there no global way of requesting a context version? If not I'll adapt my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample code for GLFW3 to create an OpenGL 3.3 Core profile context:

```
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3 );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE );
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );
```

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of supported versions?

Comment: @JeroenBollen To get the maximal supported version you have to create a compatibility profile and ask OpenGL for a version. That would be the maximal version of OpenGL available which does not break the feature set you requested.

Comment: Not quite what I asked, I would like to have a list of supported versions... :s

Comment: @JeroenBollen: All versions lesser or equal to the maximal are supported :)

Comment: @SergeyK. _To get the maximal supported version you have to create a compatibility profile and ask OpenGL for a version_: How would you ask OpenGL for a version?

Comment: Do I have to create a context to see what that is?

Comment: @legends2k: glGetString( GL_VERSION );

Comment: @JeroenBollen: It's not unusual to create a dummy window+context, enumerate versions and then create the actual one with the required context.

Comment: @legends2k: ...and required pixel format and other properties

Comment: @SergeyK: your method for getting the maximum supported version does not work reliably, and is not guaranteed to do so by any spec. This will fail especially on apple, where a compatibility profile will always report a GL version <=2.1.

Comment: @derhass: the other option is to try them all starting from 3.1